# octokit.net - how to get data on commit content

Tags: git, api, github, octokit.net

is it possible to get data from a repository such as total number of commits and more in depth data about each commit? from say a project such as jquery.

having performed some tests on a console application, I cant seem to find this functionality. this is pretty key to the project i am starting soon and may sway the use of octokit over say jgit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that octokit.net is aimed at that. That's a wrapper to easily use github apis.

Perhaps, you should better have a look at [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) for such a things...

Comment: This is correct - we don't currently support receiving webhooks in Octokit.net